# iOS: Get correct height of thirdPart keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

Since iOS8, many thirdPart keyboard shows, i want to get the keyboard height when it show

```
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo]; CGSize kbSize = 
[[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

however i can get the height of system keyboard, but can't get a thirdPart keybord(such as SouGouKeyboard),it return 0 instead how to get the correct height?

it returns :
`{
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 0}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 568}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 568}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 0}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 0}}";
}`

Comment: NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

Comment: it return ：Printing description of aNotification:
NSConcreteNotification 0x17424f4b0 {name = UIKeyboardDidShowNotification; userInfo = {
    UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey = 7;
    UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey = "0.25";
    UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 0}, {320, 0}}";
    UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 568}";
    UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey = "NSPoint: {160, 568}";
    UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 0}}";
    UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey = "NSRect: {{0, 568}, {320, 0}}";
}}

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification    
    object:nil];

 - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
  int height = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);
  int width = MAX(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);
}
```