# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification returning incorrect frame for swift keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift-keyboard

I am using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to handle keyboard.
This is the function called when keyboard is shown :

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    CGRect keyboardBounds;
    //[[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardBounds];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    keyboardBounds = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];  
}
```

I get **keyboardBounds** = (0, 524, 320, 44) and I am using 5s. No idea why **origin.y** is coming 524 (should be somewhere near 300) and height as 44 !!
I have also tried the commented line. Both ways keyboard bound comes out to be **44**. This issue comes **only for swift keyboard**.
Same as [**this issue**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740706/ios-get-correct-height-of-thirdpart-keyboard)

Comment: Looks like a race condition. Same problem when using `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`?

Comment: And listening on `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` and continuously save the frame?

Comment: @FabioPoloni I haven't registered for UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification

Comment: I still expect this to be a race condition, so `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` might give you more notifications, but could be more precise than the other notifications.

Comment: Is this on the device or the simulator? Do you have a hardware (presumably bluetooth) keyboard connected to the device, or simulator's hardware keyboard connected? (Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard)

Comment: @robmayoff : I am runnig on device 5c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the issue is with swift keyboard, the method `-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note` is called three times, and every time it returns three different origin.y value and height  first time it gives keyboardBounds = (0, 524, 320, 44), second time it it gives keyboardBounds = (0, 308, 320, 260) and finally the third time when it is called it returns keyboardBounds = (0, 271, 320, 297).

As third party keyboard sizes are not fixed.. their sizes get fixed as per how view lay it out, so as similar to autolayout case(viewDidLoad,viewWillAppear viewWillLayout,viewDidLayout and then viewDidAppear, so exact frame you get to know in viewDidAppear or viewDidLayout, where View have been laid out.), Here it gets exact frame when it's view get completely laid out.

Comment: `UIKeyboard` doesn't have open layout events.

Comment: Swift keyboard is custom keyboard, and it have events, please read the question carefully before making comments

Comment: If you face the incorrect height issue in iOS 11, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273070/2764966.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try other notifications like：`UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` ，`UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification`. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`

Just tell you the keyboard will show to you ,can not tell the exactly key board shown frame.